# Flutter: How to generate screenshots in arbitrary resolutions?

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, how do you get a screenshot for an arbitrary screen resolution? I.e. for a screen resolution that's different from the resolution the app is running in?

Is there a way to tell the Flutter engine to paint a single frame into a buffer with a specific resolution?

What I'm trying to accomplish is to generate the screenshots for the various app stores from within the app, but without scaling and cropping screenshots that were taken for different devices/resolutions.

How would you tackle that requirement?

Any advise is welcome,
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

if you are talking about taking a screenshot of a particular widget and saving it
the you have to use renderrepaint boundry with key .
dependencies - path provider
Image gallery saver ..

```
  takeScreenshot(BuildContext context,GlobalKey _key,String slug) async {
      RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = _key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
      ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 3.0);
      final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text("Image saved to gallery"));
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
    
      final directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
      ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
      final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(
          byteData.buffer.asUint8List(),
          name: "name.jpg");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing to `RenderRepaintBoundary()`. The Flutter repository contains a [copy&paste-able snippet](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40064#issuecomment-620081426) that works just perfectly to create screenshots in arbitrary resolutions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).